# Update style for all cells from DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to update style for all cells from DataGridView without iteration over them like example below?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Rows.Count; j++)
        if (dgv[i, j].Style != style)
            dgv[i, j].Style = style;
```

My question is an actual due to slow speed of slyle updating for all cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the same style to all the cells, simply use the `DefaultCellStyle` of the datagridview.

```
dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

The answer of Killercam would be helpful when you want to apply different styles to different cells on the same rows.

Comment: No, not 'different cells on the same rows' - the entire row.

Comment: But you are right. this will do what he asks with out iteration. +1.

Comment: @Killercam thank you, I mean all the cells on the same row have the same style with your code.

Comment: My code is working but yours is not. Maybe I should call some method after it?

Comment: @KvanTTT Why not? You should apply the code after the form is loaded, such as place the code in a Shown event handler. Placing the code in the Form constructor will work only for some properties. For BackColor, I tested and it works even when you change the DefaultCellStyle in the Form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a row-by-row basis:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
    Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

or

```
for (int r = 0; r < dataGridView.Rows.Count; r++)
    dataGridView.Rows[r].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

where using the `DefaultCellStyle` you can set other properties as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is used when different rows need different styles.